# IE7: block inside table with percentage-margin

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I hope there is a solution to this IE7 issue. I put an example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fCqm6/

If you switch to the IE7-Mode in your IE you will notice that the block inside the cell is positioned all the way to the right.
I wanted however it to stay positioned in the middle (as it is with Chrome or current IE version).

If I set the width of the box to a fixed value, the box is positioned quite differently. But I need to set both the width and margin as a percentage if possible (the end result is a sort of timeline where dynamic elements need to be positioned and stretched based on their duration)

Is there any hack or workaround so that these percentage margins work inside a table apart from javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured this out myself:

By adding a div between the table cell and the box with a set width of 100% IE7 renders the box correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/fCqm6/1/